# IOS Flutter run- no devices connected

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, flutter

I wrote application in flutter in android studio. I tried to build it on ios. On emulators it worked ( i tested it on all avaible version of iphone and ipad), but when i tried do the same with real device (iphone 6) all i got was

```
flutter run
No devices connected
```

Flutter doctor said only

```
Connected Device
  ! No devices connected
```

Which is strange, because my mac see this device and xcode see it too. I tried to build it in console. What can i do to make this app run on real device?

Comment: Firstly Connect the iPhone to Mac then Go the Setting of iPhone then go to general in Setting then Go to Device Management in this Show the your iCloud Id Then Click on iCloud id Open the dialog Box for Permission For Trust or Don't Trust then Click on Trust option then openYour App.

Comment: You could also open the iOS project in Xcode and upload the app from there, you will however not get hot reload, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

If you still having trouble connecting physical iOS devices, try to follow these steps [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-test-your-flutter-ios-app-on-your-ios-device-75924bfd75a8#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20go%20to,app%20on%20your%20local%20device.).

Also make sure that you are running the updated Xcode for a specific iOS version, as there are some cases that these was caused by compatibility issues as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes).

> ### Known Issues
>
> - Xcode 11.4 doesn’t work with devices running iOS 13.4 beta 1 and beta 2. (60055806)